# Changing WRAP_CONTENT to a set number using LinearLayout.LayoutParams

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, layoutparams

I have set up some `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` to set up some buttons just using java. But I want to change it from `WRAP_CONTENT` to a height and width of my choice.

```
//LinearLayout.LayoutParams top;
//this is declared at the top as it is used by different bits of the code.
top = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
            (LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    top.topMargin = 100;
    top.leftMargin = 120;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
top = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
            (90, 80);
```

// **whatever u like**

**this is from documentation:**

```
public LayoutParams(int width, int height) {
        super(width, height);
        weight = 0;
    }
```

Comment: No problem :) enjoy

Answer (score 0):

According to [ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html#setMargins](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html#setMargins(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) you have to use this:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.yourLinear_Layout);
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);            
params.setMargins(120, 100, 0, 0); //Here your custom margin (int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
layout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
top.getLayoutParams().height = 256;
top.getLayoutParams().width= 256;
top.requestLayout();
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this..

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.numberPadLayout);
// Gets the layout params that will allow you to resize the layout
LayoutParams params = layout.getLayoutParams();
// Changes the height and width to the specified *pixels*
params.height = 100;
params.width = 100;
layout.setLayoutParams(params);
```